# jQuery jump to id (no animation)

Tags: jquery, target

Script adds `id` for block, gives:

```
<div id="some">Text</div>
```

---

After that **page should jump for that `id`**, without animation, just like we have target `#some` on current page link.

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4gohxf79/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you just mean linking "old school" like #some

For example

```
<a href="#some"></a>
```

Done in JS with

```
location.href = "#some";
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
 document.getElementById('some').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: +1 because I've never heard of this before!  Surprised it works cross browser, despite not being part of the spec.  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23

Comment: It still animates

Comment: @Gleno it might do so now, due to browser behavior changes, but back when the answer was written the browsers did not do much in terms of built-in transitioning.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
location.href = "#some";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top});
return false;
e.preventDefault();
});
```