# jumpTO function of fadeslideshow library is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The plugin which i referred is: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fadeslideshow
This is my script which calls jumpTo() function

```
 var slide;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        slide=jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow();

        $('ul.dropdown-menu li a').click( function(event) {
        var newTopicContent = $(this).attr('id');
        slide.jumpTo(newTopicContent);
        });
    });
```

when i run this code, console gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: slide.jumpTo is not a function
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: when you are using third party libraries, make sure that you link the official site in the question so that its easy for others to help you.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023625/jquery-jump-to-id-no-animation This may help you.

Comment: is [this](http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/) the plugin?

Comment: i edited my question. @Cerlin Boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/ov2f9zdj/1/) implementation?

Function to jump slides

```
function jumpTo(slidenumber,restartAuto){
    $('#fssList li a').eq(parseInt(slidenumber) - 1).trigger('click');
    if(restartAuto == true){
        autoplay();
    } else {
        stopAutoplay();
    }
}
```

Call it like `jumpTo(1,true)`. `true` for auto play and `false` to stop auto play

Incase if you have more than one slider in a page then use CSS Selector to trigger the click.

Comment: Thank you. Its amazing code and working pretty well. But again if i want autoplay of slideshow. How can i perform that without using autoplaypause button. Please help. @Cerlin Boss

Comment: @ShwethaRS : I have updated the code. Hope this helps you.